# My contact us PHP Form is sending 7 emails with ever submission

Tags: php, forms, email, contacts

Well my PHP contact us form is sending email too well.....

I am getting 7 emails per submission

My setup is php.ini file mail function works.....obviously

I am using the script from http://phpfileuploader.com/

Along with a simple php contact form

http://i48.tinypic.com/2ywsf0w.png

So people fill out the form and upload a picture.

Problem is I have no idea why I am getting 7 emails per submission.

I am running WAMP latest version with MySQL, APACHE, PHP

For my mail server I am using Hmail

Any thoughts?

CODE

```
<?php require "quickcache.php"; ?>
<?php require "ieblock.php"; ?>
<?php require_once "phpuploader/include_phpuploader.php" ?> 
<!--- BEGIN CONTACT FORM --->
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
<table width="450px">
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"">
<label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="email">Email Address *</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<label for="comments">COMMENTS*</label>
</td>
<td valign="top">
<textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="9"></textarea>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
<br>
Please upload a picture of your computer 
<?php   

            $uploader=new PhpUploader();   
            $uploader->SaveDirectory="savefiles";    
            $uploader->Render();   
        ?></td>
</tr>
</table>

<!--- END CONTACT FORM --->

<!--- BEGIN SEND CONFIRMATION --->
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

// EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
$email_to = "MY EMAIL HERE";
$email_subject = "Buy my used computer, PLEASE!";


function died($error) {
// your error code can go here
echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted.  ";
echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
echo $error."<br /><br />";
echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
die();
}

// validation expected data exists
if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
!isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
!isset($_POST['email']) ||
!isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
!isset($_POST['comments'])) {
died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you   
submitted.');       
}

$first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
$last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
$email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
$telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
$comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

$error_message = "";
$email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
$error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
$string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
$error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
$error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';
}
if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
died($error_message);
}
$email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>

<!--- END SEND CONFIRMATION --->
```

This is 2 separate pages of code just fyi

some more thoughts......

In my php.ini file I have ---

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
SMTP = 127.0.0.1
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
sendmail_from = admin@MYDOMAIN.COM
```

BUT,

In my contactform.php I have buymypc@MYDOMAIN.COM and in hmail that forwards to forwarding@MYDOMAIN.COM

I have not used my actual emails for privacy reasons.

Comment: A picture of your form isn't going to help. We need code!

Comment: Lisa, please edit your post and include the code. Then only we would be able to help you.

Comment: Why have you got `@mail();`, it should just be `mail();`... (This probably isn't causing the problem though) (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

Comment: @sim_92 Prepending `@` to a function name suppresses error output. It's usually a bad idea, but common in copy-and-pasted code.

Comment: I don't see anything that should cause the email to send 7 times. You could try echoing some text at different points in the script, to see if any of them are somehow getting looped or called repeatedly. It would be even more useful to use error_log() -- that way, if the whole page is somehow getting reloaded over and over, you'll have evidence of that.

Comment: Some other questions: Does this problem happen the same way every time you use the form? Does it always send exactly seven times? Are there any differences between the headers of the seven different emails?

Comment: Yep sends exactly 7 until just now when I removed mirror from my hmail server now i just get 2 emails everytime and mail() gives a syntax error but @mail does not.

Comment: I am going to just add an account to hmail and check it directly in outlook instead of forwarding and see if this helps.

Comment: Ok found the issue....PHP.ini is set to send to admin@MYDOMAIN.COM and that forwards to an email account....and because my email in the form script is set to a different email I am getting forwards of forwards...I do believe......

Comment: Don't know if it's related, but the brace in `if(isset($_POST['email'])) {` has no matching close brace.

Comment: The close brace is there just is not listed in the code I pasted sorry  BUT they both are removable and I did so.

Comment: So my email setup is as such ---- in hmail I have the a catch all account.....catchallemail@MYDOMAIN.COM so that anything not expressly given an account goes to it....I then have my main account...MAIN@MYDOMAIN.COM......In php.ini I have ADMIN@MYDOMAIN.COM .....ADMIN forwards to MAIN in hmail and the Contact Forum email forwards to MAIN.....I am now only getting 2 emails....I am getting a double forward is what is happening. PHP.ini is sending from ADMIN which forwards to MAIN and contact forum email forwards to MAIN....Hence 2 emails......wooooooooo everyone follow?

Comment: Changed email address in php.ini file and it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by editing the email php script

Comment: Check the mark in front of your answer to make everyone know your issue is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the php `die` function after submission

```
<!--- END SEND CONFIRMATION --->
<?php
die();
?>
```